# Solving two equations simultaneously and ploting the result

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics

I have:

$$p_n = \frac{e^{-a/n - bn}}{\sum_{n = 3}^{12} e^{-a/n - bn}},$$

where $a$ and $b$ are unknown. I have also given: $\langle n \rangle = \sum_{n=3}^{12} n p_n = 6$.

Now, I need to plot $p_n$ vs. $n$ for various given $p_6$. Let's assume $p_6 = 0.5$. In principle, one should be able to obtain $a$ and $b$ with this information. Thus:

```
FindRoot[{Sum[n (E^(-a/n - b n))/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]), {n, 3, 12}] - 6, 
E^(-a/6 - b 6)/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]) - 0.5}, {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}]
```

which it returns an error that it has encountered singularity. For different initial values of the parameters $a$ and $b$ the problem still exists. How can I solve this issue?

My second question is: After solving the above, I need to do the same things for various $p_6$ let's say starting from $0.5$ to $0.05$ for small intervals. One way is to calculate for each $p_6$ and write down $a$ and $b$ and plot $p_n$ vs. $n$ and then go to the next $p_6$. Is there a more easy way to do this rather than collecting $a$ and $b$ at each step?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On MMA 13,2.0: `FindRoot[{Sum[
    n (E^(-a/n - b n))/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]), {n, 3, 
     12}] - 6, 
  E^(-a/6 - b 6)/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]) - 1/2}, {{a, 
   10}, {b, 5}}]` give me: `{a -> 165.219, b -> 4.83601}`

Comment: In both formulas you use `n` as variable index and as summation index! Please clarify your formulas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p6ab = Table[
  Join[ {p6}, 
   Values@NMinimize[# . # &[{Sum[
          n (E^(-a/n - b n))/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]), {n, 3,
            12}] - 6, 
        E^(-a/6 - b 6)/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]) - p6}], {a, 
       b}][[2]]], {p6, 1/20, 1/2, 1/20} ]
(*{{1/20, -18.9935, -0.367947}, {1/10, -3.90636, 0.077455}, 
{3/20,8.8695, 0.454294}, {1/5, 22.3032, 0.845557}, 
{1/4, 37.9416,1.29194}, {3/10, 56.6589, 1.81724}, 
{7/20, 78.702, 2.43167}, {2/5,104.128, 3.13925}, 
{9/20, 132.996, 3.94139}, {1/2, 165.219,4.83601}}*)
```

evaluates a list of values `{p6,a,b}`

The lists `{p3,p4,...p12}` for differnet `p6` follows

```
pi=Map[Table[(E^(-a/n - b n))/(Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}]), {n, 3,12}] /. {a -> #[[2]], b -> #[[3]]} &, p6ab ]
```

**addendum**

```
index = Range[3, 12];
Graphics[Map [{RandomColor[], Line[Transpose[{index, #}]]} &, pi], 
AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, GridLines -> {{6}, None}, 
AxesLabel -> {"n", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(n\)]\)"}, 
AxesOrigin -> {3, 0}]
```

[image]

**final**

```
Graphics[MapIndexed [(zw = Transpose[{index, #1}]; {RandomColor[],Line[zw], Point[zw], 
Text["p6=" <> ToString[zw[[4, 2]]],Scaled[{.7, #2[[1]]/Length[pi]}]]}) &, pi], AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True,AxesLabel -> {"n", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(n\)]\)"},AxesOrigin -> {3, 0} ]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: For given `p6` we solved for `a[p6],b[p6]`. What means `pn vs n` in this context???

Comment: @Samane See my modified answer!

Comment: Try `Graphics[Map [(zw = Transpose[{index, #}]; {RandomColor[], Line[zw], 
     Point[zw], Text["p6=" <> ToString[zw[[4,2]]], Last[zw]]}) &, pi], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"n", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(n\)]\)"}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {3, 0} ]`  Labels aren't placed optimal yet...

Comment: @Samane Sorry, now I added `index` in my modified answer

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

p[n_, a_, b_] = E^(-a/n - b n)/Sum[E^(-a/n - b n), {n, 3, 12}];

exp[a_, b_] = Sum[n*p[n, a, b], {n, 3, 12}] // Simplify;

f[p6_?NumericQ] := 
 NMinimize[{a^2 + b^2, exp[a, b] == 6, p[6, a, b] == p6}, {a, b}][[-1]]

f[1/2]

(* {a -> 165.218, b -> 4.83599} *)

funcs = Table[p[n, a, b] /. f[p6],
   {p6, 0.5, 0.05, -0.05}];

Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[funcs], {n, 3, 12},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[Range[0.5, 0.05, -0.05],
     LegendLabel -> Subscript[p, 6],
     LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}],
    {0.7, 0.6}]],
 DiscretePlot[Evaluate[funcs], {n, 3, 12},
  Filling -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: The discrete values peak at 6, the continuous functions do not. There is nothing to fix. If you just want to join the discrete points use `DiscretePlot[Evaluate[funcs], {n, 3, 12}, Filling -> None, Joined -> True]`